# Error crítico: Either log or rethrow this exception

Tags: java, sonar

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
try {
     ...
}catch (Exception ex) {
     LOG.error(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Al pasar dicho código por Jenkins (o sonar) me salta el siguiente error crítico:

> Either log or rethrow this exception.

Te da una explicación de como solucionar dicho error crítico de calidad pero al hacerlo me sigue manteniendo dicho error de calidad. ¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que solo estás logueando el mensaje de la excepción. Considera que la excepción **no es solo el mensaje**. Muchas veces conocer solo el mensaje **no dice nada sobre el problema**. Por eso Sonar te marca el error al hacer el análisis estático de código. Ejemplo de mensajes de excepción:

- "`java.lang.NullPointerException`". Ok, hay una variable nula, pero ¿dónde?, ¿en qué clase, método, línea?, ¿en cuál de todos los flujos de mi aplicación?
- "`java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " "`". Si aplicas solo una conversión de cadena a número en toda tu aplicación, esto puede ser comprensible. Pero en aplicaciones del mundo real **no es así**. Inclusive puede que no hagas tú la conversión de manera directa, puede que una librería o framework lo haga por ti. Por ejemplo, Jackson o Gson al convertir de JSON a un objeto Java.
- El peor de todos los escenarios. Algún framework o librería o quizás dentro de tu mismo código (escrito por ti tiempo atrás o por algún compañero del equipo) que relanza una excepción pero ya tiene un mensaje. Entonces loguear el mensaje solo describiría algo así: `com.mi.paquete.ExcepcionGeneral: Hubo un problema.`.

Soluciones que propone Sonar (y que vale la pena evaluar):

1. Loguear la excepción:

   ```
   catch (Exception e) {
       LOGGER.error("Mensaje de error descriptivo.", ex);
   }
   ```
2. Relanzar la excepción. Esto implica que manejarás la excepción a un nivel superior.

   ```
   catch (Exception e) {
       throw e;
   }
   ```

   Si tu método no declara que lanza excepciones, puedes encapsular la excepción dentro de una excepción de tipo `RuntimeException` o alguna clase hija de esta clase. Ejemplo:

   ```
   catch (Exception e) {
       throw new RuntimeException("Problema en la operación foo." ,e);
   }
   ```

La estrategia a escoger depende de lo que haga el método y del propósito del código escrito. Por ejemplo, si escribes un framework, lo mejor será relanzar la excepción y que el código cliente se encargue de manejar la excepción. Si el código que escribes es código cliente o código preciso para manejo de excepciones, lo recomendable es loguear la excepción y tratar de devolver al usuario un mensaje más amigable.